# Can I ask for higher salary if I work remotely in a more expensive location than where the company is located?

Tags: salary, telecommute, cost-of-living

If a company is located in a location where the cost of living is fairly low, is it fair to ask for a salary increase based on the fact I will be working from a significantly more expensive location?

This question is more pertaining to starting salary negotiation as a remote developer at a new company.  Moving will not be an option.

Comment: Is the choice of the more expensive location due to the employer's requirements or your preferences?

Comment: Also similar: [How to negotiate salary based on Quality of life?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48270/how-to-negotiate-salary-based-on-quality-of-life)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If living there is necessary for your position, or you currently live there (where cost of living is higher than the company's location), asking for a salary that accounts for the cost of living is reasonable. I would do some research and look at what the cost of living differences are between your location and the company's location so that you have some good evidence behind your request. Even if the difference in cost of living is obvious, knowing what it is should give you a stronger point of negotiation.

However, if you simply want to take advantage of the fact that you'll be working remotely and move to a nicer area where the cost of living is higher, I wouldn't expect much from the company. That seems more like you're taking advantage of any cost of living adjustment they'd give you rather than doing it because it's necessary.

Basically, I think you need a justification for moving to that city if you want the company to compensate you for it. If they can ask you "Why can't you live close to the office?" and you don't have a good reason besides "I don't wanna," I don't think you'll get your raise.